# Remove everything besides a certain html tag and its content in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've search around the internet and I cannot find anything that will exclude everything besides a certain tag and its content inside it.

How can I do this with Python (beautifulsoup 4)?

I have this html:

```html
<p><iframe width="1000" height="500" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" class="embed" src="#"> </iframe></p>
<p>sdkjasdkljasldjad;j dadas dasdadada</p>
```

I need to remove all other so the output is like this:

```html
<iframe width="1000" height="500" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" class="embed" src="#"> </iframe>
```

I've come up with this but it don't know how to go further:

```
@register.filter(name='only_iframe')
def only_iframe(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

    for tag in soup.find_all('p', 'strong'):
        tag.replaceWith('')

    return soup.get_text()
```

Comment: Maybe RegEx will help, just an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't locate the `iframe` and get its *string representation*:

```
iframe = soup.find("iframe", class_="embed")
print(str(iframe))
```